# Get Weekday from timestamp using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I would like to extract the weekday from a timestamp I am getting from a JSON file located [here](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=Toulouse&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&APPID=03b3e54d35f07973146a9b384e4554df).

The timestamp is located in a variable called `"dt"`.

This is the code part where I run through the JSON file using AngularJS :

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="t in weather.list">
        <div class="date">
            {{t.dt*1000 | date:'EEE'}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

It is supposed to return the current weekday as well as the next ten weekdays, something like this :

```
Sun
Mon
Tue
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
Sun
Mon
Tue
```

But this is what I get :

```
Sun
Sun
Sun
Mon
Mon
Mon
Mon
Mon
Mon
Mon
```

The `dt` values of the array:

```
1463335200
1463346000
1463356800
1463367600
1463378400
1463389200
1463400000
1463410800
1463421600
1463432400
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: can you show an example output you would expect?

Comment: @SerhanOztekin check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaves correctly [Your json](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=Toulouse&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&APPID=03b3e54d35f07973146a9b384e4554df)  has 10 entries and 10 dates.

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w33r379e/2/

I user normal JavaScript date object to parse your date.

```
const date = new Date(entry.dt*1000);
```

open your console and look at the results.

If you are using the above object as your date source you wont get the days like you expect because they are simply not there.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code here, it shows what your data says :)

*http://www.epochconverter.com/*

Tried this link with your timestamps and got the exact days.